# Roxie Query Returns (Failed to get response from server for dynamic file callback)

Tags: hpcc-ecl

I have a roxie service that using package map to read the virtual files that are stored on roxie, so basically you pass a name and it finds the match adn returns the result. It is working for  most of the sceanrios but when I connect it to a web service and start hitting the API, I see the following logs

````
000B975D PRG 2022-11-16 02:20:29.992 2485569 2497763 "RoxieMemMgr: Heap size 4096 pages, 3509 free, largest block 2340, heapLWM 0, heapHWM 128, dataBuffersActive=0, dataBufferPages=0"
000B975E PRG 2022-11-16 02:20:31.013 2485569 1436086 "[172.16.1.100:9876{89123}:checkcomplianceperson.10@136] Channel 1 blocked by flow control: uid=0x00000635 activityId=136 pri=LOW queryHash=f9ee84b1f2b56628 ch=1 seq=10 cont=0 server=172.16.1.100"
000B975F PRG 2022-11-16 02:20:31.014 2485569 1436087 "[172.16.1.100:9876{89123}:checkcomplianceperson.10@147] Channel 1 blocked by flow control: uid=0x00000638 activityId=147 pri=LOW queryHash=f9ee84b1f2b56628 ch=1 seq=10 cont=0 server=172.16.1.100"
000B9760 PRG 2022-11-16 02:20:32.013 2485569 1436086 "[172.16.1.100:9876{89123}:checkcomplianceperson.10@136] Channel 1 blocked by flow control: uid=0x00000635 activityId=136 pri=LOW queryHash=f9ee84b1f2b56628 ch=1 seq=10 cont=0 server=172.16.1.100"
000B9761 PRG 2022-11-16 02:20:32.014 2485569 1436087 "[172.16.1.100:9876{89123}:checkcomplianceperson.10@147] Channel 1 blocked by flow control: uid=0x00000638 activityId=147 pri=LOW queryHash=f9ee84b1f2b56628 ch=1 seq=10 cont=0 server=172.16.1.100"
000B9762 PRG 2022-11-16 02:20:33.013 2485569 1436086 "[172.16.1.100:9876{89123}:checkcomplianceperson.10@136] Channel 1 blocked by flow control: uid=0x00000635 activityId=136 pri=LOW queryHash=f9ee84b1f2b56628 ch=1 seq=10 cont=0 server=172.16.1.100"
000B9763 PRG 2022-11-16 02:20:33.014 2485569 1436087 "[172.16.1.100:9876{89123}:checkcomplianceperson.10@147] Channel 1 blocked by flow control: uid=0x00000638 activityId=147 pri=LOW queryHash=f9ee84b1f2b56628 ch=1 seq=10 cont=0 server=172.16.1.100"
000B9764 PRG 2022-11-16 02:20:33.994 2485569 2485871 "PING: 1 replies received, average delay 22us"
000B9765 PRG 2022-11-16 02:20:34.013 2485569 1436086 "[172.16.1.100:9876{89123}:checkcomplianceperson.10@136] Channel 1 blocked by flow control: uid=0x00000635 activityId=136 pri=LOW queryHash=f9ee84b1f2b56628 ch=1 seq=10 cont=0 server=172.16.1.100"
000B9766 PRG 2022-11-16 02:20:34.014 2485569 1436087 "[172.16.1.100:9876{89123}:checkcomplianceperson.10@147] Channel 1 blocked by flow control: uid=0x00000638 activityId=147 pri=LOW queryHash=f9ee84b1f2b56628 ch=1 seq=10 cont=0 server=172.16.1.100"
000B9767 PRG 2022-11-16 02:20:35.010 2485569 3990418 "timed out waiting for server callback - retrying"
000B9768 PRG 2022-11-16 02:20:35.010 2485569 1312353 "timed out waiting for server callback - retrying"
000B9769 PRG 2022-11-16 02:20:35.011 2485569 777157 "timed out waiting for server callback - retrying"```


I have updated the package map, I have tried the DYNAMIC(filename) file read option but that is not ideal as it will calcualte the metadata again.
````

Answer (score 2):

If you haven't done so already, please open a Jira report with the above content and steps to reproduce. You can even post the workunit name and cluster you are using so that the development team can look at this.
To open an issue, go to [Community Issue Tracker](https://track.hpccsystems.com/secure/Dashboard.jspa)
Thank you!